# How to use list comprehension to output number of insects in a list?

Tags: python, data-structures

I recently started learning python, and now I am learning python data structures. I feel like I don’t completely understand how list comprehensions work. Here is the following problem:

> The number of insects in a lab doubles in size every month. Take the
> initial number of insects as input and output a list, showing the
> number of insects for each of the next 12 months, starting with 0,
> which is the initial value. So, the resulting list should contain 12
> items, each showing the number of insects at the beginning of that
> month.

My code attempt:

```
n = int(input())
list = [2**(i-1) for i in range(n, 13)]
print(list)
```

But I am not getting desired outputs after inputting different numbers.

Comment: You're using `n` in the wrong place in that calculation.  It has nothing to do with the number of months, which is fixed at 12.  The first term `2**(i-1)` should be multiplied by `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not call a variable `list`, because `list` is a built-in list constructor (this is not a mistake in your case but potentially may become a mistake). Other than that, you are close to a correct solution:

```
[n * 2**i for i in range(12)]
#[25, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400, 12800, 25600, 51200]
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the answer, you could use the `walrus` operator. A good approach for this would be:

```py
n = input("Enter no. of insects: ")  #e.g. input = '33'
result = int(n)                      # gets changed to 33 (int)
comprehension = [result := 2 * result  for _ in range (12)]

# comprehension = [66, 132, 264, 528, 1056, 2112, 4224, 8448, 16896, 33792, 67584, 135168]
```

More about the walrus (`:=`) operator [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

**TIP**: In python, `list` is a built-in function. Since you named your list as `list`, it is conflicting with that function, but would be over-written.

In REPL mode, this code would not work (outputs `<class 'list'>`) because of its nature of line-by-line execution, and in normal file-based execution, this you would not be able to use the `list()` function over-writing the list variable.

So I've renamed the `list` variable to `comprehension`.

Comment: Not true. `list` is not a reserved keyword, and it is not conflicting with anything. The new variable simply overwrites the built-in function, but _in this example_ it does not cause any trouble.

Comment: However, on my version (python 3.9.2), the `print(list)` command is returning `<class 'list'>`

Comment: `list` isn't a python reserved keyword, but isn't a good practice to use builtin function names as a variable name.

Comment: So what? It is the built-in class constructor and can be overwritten, just like any other function or variable.

Comment: @DYZ because the next time you try to use that function you'll get an error.

Comment: Okay, then I'll edit this question. I think I'm a bit confused between reserved functions and reserved keywords.

Comment: But this does get errored out in REPL mode.

Comment: @DYZ is right. Nothing happens even if you override the built in functions. That code works fine without any issue

Comment: @PrakashDahal Yep, I know. Actually executed it in REPL mode, so got unexpected results. Currently, editing the answer.

Comment: @DYZ I've edited the question. Is it correct now?